# Animated html5 buttons on press

Tags: html, animation, button, pressed

I'm wondering if there is a way I can animate a button when it is pressed (NOT rolled over) using HTML5/javascript?

I want to create an almost cartoonish button that expands a little when pressed and sparkles. I know that sounds kinda gawdy but I think the final result would look better than it sounds.

My inspiration is the ? blocks in the new Super Mario Brothers games.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is created by CSS3, not HTML5.

Here's a blog post with links to ten different tutorials on making all sorts of cool buttons with CSS3: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-css3-buttons-tutorials.

Many of the buttons expand and stuff when rolled over by using the :hover selector. If you want a style to be applied when pressed, just substitute the :active selector instead.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thank you for the link.Those are some nice looking buttons. I'll have to read though them to see what they can do. But on the surface most of them look like they only have and up and down state. I'm looking for a way to do something animated with about 6-10 frames or so. I want to be able to make a star fly up and flip around and then fall back down on the button when it's pressed. Plus like I said, make the button expand a little like a pillow does when you press on it. Maybe some of those tutorials can do that. But I haven't seen anything like I'm thinking outside of flash.

Comment: Some of what you are talking about may require CSS3 animations. I haven't seen exactly what you described, but here are some buttons that use CSS Animations: http://www.zurb.com/playground/radioactive-buttons http://www.webrisorsa.info/animated-effects-on-buttons-with-pure-css3/362/

Comment: Thank you for the links. That first link is definitely getting closer to what I'm looking for.
I think I might have figured out what I need to do. I believe what I need are two different gif images. One that is solid and one that is animated. Then I just need to switch between the two with CSS3 or javascript when it is clicked on. So basically the button starts out solid, then on click the animated gif plays once and returns to either the solid gif or a second solid gif that colored differently, showing that the button was already clicked on.